# How to set sha256 signature algorithm for soap signature in .Net

Tags: sha256

I created a PKCS12 certificate that is installed in my windows trust store. When I create a soap signature by using this certificate in .Net I get the signature algorithm as SHA1. Is it possible to change this algorithm for message signature as it is throwing error when processing the response.

Answer (score 0):

i have been researching a couple of days (5+), i havent been able to find a solution, i am using wse 3.0 and for that is pretty much imposible.

so if you are using wse 2.0 or 3.0, the answer is no, you cant change the inner cyrpto provider, or even subclass the securitytoken class and override the signatureformatter getter.

Comment: What is *wse*? I don't see *wse* in the question.

Comment: the microsoft way to sign soaps on .net

she doesnt mention the way she's signing the soap, so its to assume shes using wse.